# how to resign UIAlertview on textFileldShouldReturn?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5

I am having UIAlertview with UITextField in that.Mine is iPad application

```
-(void)showAlertToAddLink
{
    alertToAddLink =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ADD", nil];
    alertToAddLink.tag = 2;
    alertToAddLink.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [txtLinkName setDelegate:self];

    /*
    UITextField *txtLinkName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 50.0, 260.0, 50.0)];
    [txtLinkName setDelegate:self];
//    txtLinkName.text=@"";
    [txtLinkName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0]];
    [txtLinkName setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:71.0/255.0 green:78.0/255.0 blue:80.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
    [txtLinkName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [txtLinkName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [txtLinkName setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [txtLinkName setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    [txtLinkName setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [txtLinkName setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    [txtLinkName setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
   // [txtLinkName becomeFirstResponder];
    [alertToAddLink addSubview:txtLinkName];
    */[alertToAddLink show];

}
```

I tried with

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [alertToAddLink resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

But alertview is not being resig.

What is the way to do that

Comment: what is your OS version?

Comment: it is ios5.but i want to run on lower versions too.That is why for testing i comment out code

Comment: if you want to run below versions then add textField to alertview using add subview....and use @aman method in textFieldShouldReturn method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your `textFieldShouldReturn:`.

This will trigger dismissal of your alert view when `textFieldShouldReturn:` will be called:

```
 [alertToAddLink dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:alertToAddLink.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: +1 for a good answer :) . @Aman I have edited your answer as we are not sure that index 0 is always cancelButton Index. I didn't believe in posting duplicate answer with minor change. So just edited your answer. Hope this is fine

Comment: @ParthBhatt I need to disappear alertview on keyboard return key and this is for cancel button

Comment: @Roshni: I think you should put this line under your `textFieldShouldReturn` Delegate method. So this will dismiss the alert view when `textFieldShouldReturn` is called.

Comment: @Aman: I just informed you as the answer was posted by you. :)